# General question on recursively defined functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, self-learning

While I'm still familiarizing myself with the general picture of combinatorics, and maybe pure math and general; the process of doing so attracts me to (perhaps) smaller parts of it which I find tantalizing to pursue. I don't believe I have yet developed a (completely) stable understanding of discrete mathematics, hence I feel the need to ask for help from the more professional.

While I was trying to contemplate the idea of recursively defined functions, I entertained myself with the following function: $f_0 = 5$ and $f_n = f_{n – 1} + 2$. I soon realized myself being able to try and define the function $f_n$ in terms of $n$ directly. Hence I found that I can follow a general pattern that I can derive consequently:
$f_n = f_{n – 2} + 2 + 2$, $f_n = f_{n – 3} + 2 + 2 + 2$,
$f_n = f_{n – 4} + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2$.

Judging by the progression of this pattern based or sheer intuition, I generalized the function to be: $f_n = f_0 + 2n$. Therefore, I have defined the function $f$ in terms of $n$ itself. What is the generalization of this method? Just now I intuitively identified the end product of a pattern; how do I do this systematically?

My request is that I would like to learn more about this procedure. I have searched multiple sources using multiple keywords hoping to find the right one, but without guidance I am lost. I have found myself incapable of converting the recursive function into a regular function of $n$ when it came to the Fibonacci function, for example ($f_n = f_{n – 1} + f_{n – 2}$); or how would I go about converting a regural function to a recursively defined one. For example, maybe defining $f_n = 2n + 4$ recursively? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not every recursive function is "unfolded" by the same technique. You can use undetermined coefficients (in the same way for differential equations via an ansatz), generating functions, or just tinkering around.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence

Answer (score 1):

You asked

> Just now I intuitively identified the end product of a pattern; how do I do this systematically?

but intuition, by definition, can not be systematized.
However, over time, mathematicians have worked on specific kinds of recursive functions and found some direct formulas for them as described in the
Wikipedia article
[Recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation).

You also asked

> how would I go about converting a regular function to a recursively defined one.

which is a very general question which requires the
precise definition of a regular function and recursive
function. However, there are algorithms that given
sufficiently many function values as a sequence
$(a_1,a_2,\dots)$ can find implicit recurrence relations
such as, for example, $$0 = -a_{n+2} +a_{n+1} +a_n$$ if
such relations exist.